# Shadow-casting shaders in Stage3D

Tags: actionscript-3, fragment-shader, vertex-shader, stage3d, agal

I've been working a lot with AGAL vertex and fragment shaders. I've got individual objects lit correctly (including specular shading) but I'd like to have objects cast shadows on OTHER objects. I have looked online, but I think most people working directly with AGAL have built custom Stage3D libraries and the shadow-casting solution doesn't seem to be in the public domain. Anyone willing to change that?
I'd like to know how to get an object to cast a shadow on another. I can't post what I've tried, because I can't get my head around where to begin on this problem. How would you pass the information (whether other objects are blocking the light) into another object's shader?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IT's called Deferred shading, you have to do 2 pass of vertex and fragment shaders.
In the first pass you accumulate informations about distances, normals, occlusion...
In the second pass you render and apply the informations of the first pass to make shadows.

Another options is ShadowMapping:

Basic shadowmap

The basic shadowmap algorithm consists in two passes. First, the scene is rendered from the point of view of the light. Only the depth of each fragment is computed. Next, the scene is rendered as usual, but with an extra test to see it the current fragment is in the shadow.

The “being in the shadow” test is actually quite simple. If the current sample is further from the light than the shadowmap at the same point, this means that the scene contains an object that is closer to the light. In other words, the current fragment is in the shadow.